# How to Hang event to parent in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

How to hang event to parent in this example? Why this code do not work?

```
$(document).on('click', '.one:parent', function(){
    console.log(1);
    return false;
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zdtn2xog/

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:parent` selector selects "all elements that have at least one child node (either an element or text)."

If you want to delegate the event for elements that have children with class of `one` you can use `:has` selector:

```
$(document).on('click', ':has(> .one)', function(e){
```

Comment: what a clever reverse engineering !.

Comment: @DmitriyKupriyanov if this answer helped in resolving your issue, please accept it by clicking the green "V" on the left

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you wanted, but would this work for your use case?

```
$(".one").parent().on('click', function(){
    console.log(1);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: judging from op's syntax, he might need event delegation on which case your solution will not work

Comment: @benaryorg and this is why i did not downvote you :)

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
 $(document).on('click', $('.one',this), function(){
    console.log(1);
    return false;
 });
```

Comment: You can't pass a jQuery object as a selector to `on`.

Comment: Not  work. Click work on all document. I need work click only exactly on <a>

Comment: the syntax is equivalent to `$(document).on('click',function(){` because the selector part is not recognized